How is message waiting conveyed to home POTS phone
The message-waiting indicator is often described as a LED that lights up when you have voicemail.  It may be voicemail on a voicemail service provided by the overall phone service provider.
I haven't been able to find any description of how the message-waiting status is conveyed to the home phone.  Can someone please explain, and maybe cite a backing reference?

If you want to explore it in depth, read this from Sandman.com. This is a site where telecom techs get information and testing procedures. FSK is the method all telcos moved to or soon will if they stay in biz.
Sand Man

That was a very informative page. 1200 baud FSK. For binary FSK, the bandwidth is the difference in the two frequencies plus twice the bandwidth of the baseband modulation signal (here and here).

They might use more than 2-level FSK (haven't found any details). And it only sends this information when the phone is on-hook. Alternate names: FSK Message Waiting, Illuminated Message Waiting, CLASS Message Waiting. It has supplanted Stutter Dial Tone Message Waiting Lights, which loads down the central office.

Link only answers are discouraged because the page can become unavailable at any time. Can you summarize the content into your answer?

In addition to the dial tone stutter mentioned in Spehro Pefhany's answer, FSK-based ADSI (i.e. the same channel used for caller ID on POTS lines) also provides a message-waiting indicator that can light an LED or indicator. Wikipedia has some details, the actual spec (Telcordia GR-1401) is paid and I do not have access to it to confirm.

Thanks, naonfarad.  I upvoted your answer.  If I could mark more than one answer, I would mark this.  I found that Sand Man backgrounder on Message Waiting provided the details that I was seeking.

POTS (Plain Ordinary Telephone Service) indicates MWI by the 'stutter' dial tone. You can find lots of online information on connecting PBXs.
See nanofarad's answer for the on-hook method, and also this related patent.

Thanks, I did run across stuttering dial tones, but I assumed that there is no dial tone when the phone is on-hook.  That's why I looked for another explanation.  Was my assumption incorrect?

Yes, that's correct. I think nanofarad +1 has your right answer.  See also the link above for a related patent (of course the implementation may differ from the patent) if you don't want to spend $455 on the standard.

Sorry, when you say that is correct, do you mean that there is no dial tone when phone is on-hook, or are you agreeing that I was wrong about that?  I'm still following up on nanofarad's answer by googling ADSI to better picture where the FSK signalling occurs. For example, whether it is just riding on top of DC on the twisted pair, and what frequencies are used. I don't need the spec, I just need to understand what the MWI status delivery is called so that I can search for ATA's that support it (or confirm that they all support it).

From my googling, MWI refers to the lighting of the LED.  When I find online that most ATAs support MWI, I realized that I need to look beyond whether they have a MWI LED and confirm that they are able to properly convey the MWI status to a POTS phone (which has its own MWI LED) using standardized signalling for the MWI status. Also, when most ATAs support stutter indication, I would like to be sure that this signalling is active when the phone is on-hook.

I think you are correct about that.

I have a POTS cordless phone which connects to an Ooma VOIP internet phone.  When the Ooma gets a voicemail, it generates a "Voicemail message" display on the POTS phone, apparently using the POTS signal protocol, which occurs when the phone is on-hook.
